# Function to determine how many pages to download

Tags: python

The following basic function helps me calculate how many pages I need to download to retrieve all the links I need if there are 12 links on a web page.

I've included this basic code to show what I am trying to achieve but want something that scales to any number of pages.  What is the most pythonic way to achieve this?

```
def divideBy12(n):
    if n <= 12:
        result = 1
    elif n <= 24:
        result = 2
    return result 

divideBy12(5)
1
```

Comment: Try calculating `total_number_of_links // number_of_links_per_page` and then fix the edge cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `math.ceil`

```
from math import ceil
def divideBy12(n):
    return ceil(n / 12)
```

Here are some tests

```
for i in (0, 1, 12, 13, 24, 25, 36, 37):
    print("nb_links:", i, "nb_pages:", divideBy12(i))


nb_links: 0, nb_pages: 0
nb_links: 1, nb_pages: 1
...
nb_links: 12, nb_pages: 1
nb_links: 13, nb_pages: 2
...
nb_links: 24, nb_pages: 2
nb_links: 25, nb_pages: 3
...
nb_links: 36, nb_pages: 3
nb_links: 37, nb_pages: 4
```

Comment: 11, 23, 35, ... are edge cases, too.

Comment: @ack No, they are not the last value before the changement, I'd just show the previous and next value of the changement